# Javascript Gallery sliders that can be touch/swiped on mobile AND clicked and dragged on desktop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, gallery

I'm looking for a Javascript/jQuery gallery slider plugin which works by touch/swiping left right on mobile devices AND by clicking and dragging on desktop/laptops.

Most I've seen can do swipe on mobile but aren't "draggable" on desktop/laptop. You have to click between images. Examples of that: http://galleria.io/  http://swipejs.com/

Comment: Actually swipejs is kinda weird because it says it's IE7+ compatible but I don't think it's even desktop compatible.

Comment: swipejs works pretty well on Mac chrome but you could be right, haven't tested browsers extensively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling for a bit I answered my own question. Here's a good site http://www.iosscripts.com/iosslider/. The swiping/clicking works great on both my Mac laptop with 10.7.4 and on my iPhone 4 with iOS4.

Comment: That is a great slider... I don't like its commercial price though ;)

Comment: pricing seems pretty standard to me

Answer (score 6):

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

I like the transitions effects!

Comment: I think iosscripts performs better on iOS devices but thanks for the link

Comment: That is some awesome slider!